# Eclipse Che - Bitnami Stack

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-che

I was having a lot of issues with installing docker in Linux Mint 17.3 which runs in the virtualbox.  I've downloaded the bitnami Eclipse Che Virtual Machines (Che 5.0) and installed it in the virtualbox.  I am trying to create the workspace and I get the time out error. The last step showing in the log says "Deploying web application archive /home/user/che/ws-agent/webapps/ROOT.war". Then the message says "Error:Timeout.  The Che serve is unable to ping your workspace.  This implies a network configuration issue, workspace boot failure, or an unusually slow workspace boot."  I've signed on as the default user id "bitnami" and the log mentions "/home/user/che" folders..  Is this why I can't get the eclipse che's workspace started?

TIA,

Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was using linux mint 17.3, the correct way to install docker is

```
sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ \
   ubuntu-trusty \
   main"
```

This will set the correct repository and i was able to install docker and eclipse/che without any problems.  Also this will install the newest version of che as well.